# Cannot display data from Access in Python (via SQL)

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, select, tkinter

I want Python to display data from Access by SELECT (SQL) but there is an error. The data and database are existed. What is a problem?

```
from tkinter import *
import pypyodbc
import ctypes

#Create connection
con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL;DBQ=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL/PITL.mdb;')
cursor = con.cursor ()

form = Tk ()
form.title ("Main")
form.geometry ('400x400')

def Show ():
    cursor.execute ("SELECT `Law_ID` FROM Laws WHERE Fine='1'")
    for row in cursor:
        print (row)

Button=Button(form, text = 'PUSH ME', command = Show)
Button.pack ()

form.mainloop ()

con.commit ()
cursor.close ()
con.close ()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\PITL\SHOW DATA.py", line 14, in Show
    cursor.execute ("SELECT `Law_ID` FROM Laws WHERE Fine='1'")   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1652, in execdirect
    check_success(self, ret)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 977, in ctrl_err
    raise DataError(state,err_text) pypyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора.')
```

Comment: On a side note, you're only retrieving data. You only need to commit when you're applying changes. Hence your code line **con.commit()** is redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you're using looks like MySQL, not Access SQL.

In Access SQL, you delimit a field name by using square brackets `[]` and you don't add apostrophes for numbers, like an integer:

`"SELECT [Law_ID] FROM Laws WHERE [Fine]=1"`

You do need the apostrophes if the `Fine` column actually contains a string.